# Setting Up a Cronjob on MAMP - InfinteWP

Tags: php, cron, mamp

I am installing InfiniteWP on a local environment using MAMP. Everything works perfectly except for my inability to figure out how to setup a cronjob properly. I did find some information (dated?).

I found this: http://www.freewaytalk.net/thread/view/114906 . But am a bit worried that I may be implementing something dated.

The instruction given by InfiniteWP in order to start the cronjob say this:"php -q -d safe_mode=Off /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IWP/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1" So I need instruction on how to implement this php command on my Mac. Terminal?

I'd really appreciate advice and validation on the best course of action.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a GUI such as : http://code.google.com/p/cronnix/

This is simply a front end to the crontab tool, then simply set the time you want it to run and the URL to:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/IWP/cron.php
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any luck with that google code option but Mac has cron natively and your InfiniteWP code can be added in a few lines. See instructions here: http://www.maclife.com/article/columns/terminal_101_creating_cron_jobs